# ReadTheDocs build error. Error message incompehensible

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Since I've added `tqdm` as a dependency to my project build started failing with error like below:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/pychastic/builds/15291280/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 280, in build_main
    app.build(args.force_all, filenames)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 344, in build
    self.builder.build_update()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 296, in build_update
    len(to_build))
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 358, in build
    self.write(docnames, list(updated_docnames), method)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 532, in write
    self._write_serial(sorted(docnames))
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 542, in _write_serial
    self.write_doc(docname, doctree)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py", line 626, in write_doc
    self.docwriter.write(doctree, destination)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docutils/writers/__init__.py", line 78, in write
    self.translate()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/writers/html.py", line 71, in translate
    self.document.walkabout(visitor)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docutils/nodes.py", line 214, in walkabout
    if child.walkabout(visitor):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docutils/nodes.py", line 214, in walkabout
    if child.walkabout(visitor):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docutils/nodes.py", line 214, in walkabout
    if child.walkabout(visitor):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docutils/nodes.py", line 206, in walkabout
    visitor.dispatch_visit(self)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/util/docutils.py", line 477, in dispatch_visit
    method(node)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pychastic/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydata_sphinx_theme/bootstrap_html_translator.py", line 34, in visit_table
    self._table_row_index = 0
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

---

I'm unable to reproduce this locally making it especially annoying. What's going on?

Comment: Managed to reproduce locally. Sphinx version 4.3 makes this error appear. Investigating Further

Answer (score 2):

The issue was change of default version of Sphinx on ReadTheDocs.

It turns out it's incompatible with old versions of some theme packages.

In my case changing `requirements.txt` to

```
sphinx-book-theme==0.1.7
pydata-sphinx-theme==0.7.2
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Rather, it's an incompatibility between sphinx-pydata-theme<0.7.2 and Sphinx==4.3.0: https://github.com/pydata/pydata-sphinx-theme/issues/515